# PHP localhosting and registering testing using wampserver?

Tags: php, localhost

I was wondering since i can't use my isp smtp server is there a way for me to setup my localhost wampserver on my computer to just send the info to my yahoo email address in order to test my registration script instead of using the smtp server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) e.g. ships with the [mercury mail server](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm).
You can also use something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) without having your own MTA up and running.